# Trilogy with giant (6') earthworm like aliens in the first novel and, cannibalistic people in the second novel

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for the author of a trilogy, possibly from the 80's or 90's. The "hero" is attacked early in the first novel by a gang that has genetically modified themselves to be like werewolves (or use some kind of electronic disguise).  Next, he is contracted by aliens who are basically like 6' earthworms that live in a big hole that the hero needs to descend to visit.  There is a creepy story in the second novel where he is captive and forced to kill people on an assembly line so the humans he works for can eat them.  He gets in trouble because he comforts a young boy before killing him, thus tainting the taste because he didn't die in terror.  Weird trilogy but I'd like to read them again.

Comment: I have verified Trip Space-Parasite's answer and am enjoying the first novel, it seems that Ray Aldridge is still alive but only wrote the three novels, two of his short stories were Nebula nominees.  http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/aldridge_ray

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is the "Emancipator" trilogy, by Ray Aldridge
([The Pharaoh Contract](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553291181),
[Emperor of Everything](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0553294911), and
[The Orpheus Machine](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/055329119X)), based on the scene you mention from the second book, where the protagonist is taken captive and forced to manually operate the human slaughterhouse. It's been so long since I read the series that I don't recognize the other scenes you mention, but they seem to fit with the overall feel.

Comment: Maybe that's why I didn't remember them! Or maybe OP meant 6' in diameter...

Comment: I've downloaded the three books from Amazon.ca and will verify they these are the ones I'm thinking of, the descriptions on Amazon didn't quite jog my memory.

Comment: Yes, the *werewolves* are called *wolfheads* in the first book. The six foot earthworms are probably a slight misremembering of the *Gench*, who smell like earthworms.